# facing problem while appending dictionaries of list

Tags: python

```
 for li in list2:
            tid=li
            for i,li2 in enumerate(list):
                s2=li2
                if (s2.find(tid)>0 ):
                    i+=1
                    s3=list[i]
                    y=s3.find('RUNNABLE')
                    if( y>0 ) :
                        dict={tid:[].append('RUNNABLE')
```

I am trying to append a dictionary and the list .
The outer loop will fetch element from the list which will ultimately be the key and the inner loop will append the list .
but the output is {'tid=value': None}

Comment: Please indent correctly as in python indentation changes semantics

Comment: Inputs to your code are known only to you. Please share it along with expected output for those.

Comment: Don't name your variables ``list`` and ``dict``, you're shadowing the built-ins!

Comment: can anyone provide me example of dictionary of list where you append dictionary and list from nested loop

Comment: please define what you mean by 'appending a list and a dict' ? if you can give an example input and output it would be helpfull

Comment: @saurabhkapoor can you provide an example of the list you are working with? it's not clear from the code what it should look like.

Comment: for example there is a dictionary called dict ={} in which key is a string and the value is  a list . so, for every corresponding key you have a list for it . for key1 there is a list and for key2 there is separate list and I want to append the list for a particular key . the outer loop (list) specify the key and the inner loop (list) has the key value . so when the key value is found the next element of list is searched and if runnable state is found then for every key element the runnable string is added to the list .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `dict={tid:[].append('RUNNABLE')`. Try this:

```
print([].append('RUNNABLE'))
```

The return value of `append` is `None`. What you wanted to do is probably this:

```
a = {}
a.setdefault('foo', []).append('RUNNABLE')
print(a) # {'foo': ['RUNNABLE']}
a.setdefault('foo', []).append('RUNNABLE')
print(a) # {'foo': ['RUNNABLE', 'RUNNABLE']}
```

The method `setdefault` inserts the second argument under the key if it is absent and returns it. Otherwise it just returns it. A single use of it like this is:

```
if 'foo' not in a:
    a['foo'] = []
a['foo'].append('RUNNABLE')
```

Another solution for your problem is [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but it's a little overkill for a simple case like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, would that be the proposal?

```
list_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_values = ['not RUNNABLE', 'not RUNNABLE', 'c RUNNABLE']
list_dict = []

for key in list_keys:
    for index, value in enumerate(list_values):
        if key in value:
            if 'RUNNABLE' in value:
                list_dict.append({key: ['RUNNABLE']})
print(list_dict)
```